# Как правильно опубликовать на github проект, созданный на базе чужого проекта, но с существенно дополненной функциональностью

Tags: github

Я вижу два пути:

1. Создать Fork. Но тогда, как я понимаю, мой проект не будет участвовать в поиске, а я хочу, чтобы люди могли его найти по названиям функций, которые в нём реализованы
2. Сделать отдельный самостоятельный репозиторий, где написать на основе чего он был сделан.

Как будет правильно поступить?

Comment: Моё субъективное мнение: 2 вариант.

Comment: Если вы координально переделываете чужой проект и имеете на это право - тогда второй. Но лучше конечно fork, т.к. в этом то и состоит его основная идея.

Comment: @Andrew Спасибо, я тоже склоняюсь сейчас к этому решению. Ведь главная задача - чтобы люди, которым нужен новый функционал, смогли найти мой моё решение.

Comment: @AlexeyKapustsin точно в этом основная идея? Если могли бы пояснить или дать какие-то ссылки, я был бы признателен. Пока я прихожу к выводу, что fork-и предназначены, чтобы доработать существующий проект именно для своих нужд, а не для общего пользования

Comment: @Andrew Прочитайте к примеру вот эту [эту](https://rustycrate.ru/%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0/2016/03/07/contributing.html) статью.  Вы поймёте для чего сделан fork и pull-request

Comment: @AlexeyKapustsin Огромное спасибо за столь полезную документацию.